# Laravel Controller HTML ouput

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to output html output from ajax request as below:

```
public function fetchFiles(Request $request)
{

    $application_id = $request->get('application_id');
    $applicant_id = $request->get('applicant_id');


    $data = DB::table('applicant_attachments')
        ->where('applicant_id','=', $applicant_id)->where('application_id','=', $application_id)->get();

    $output = '<table border="2">';
    $myAction="viewDOC";

    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<tr><td><form name="view_attachie" id="view_attachie" class="row" action="'.$myAction .'" method="post">@csrf</td>   <td>' .$myToken .'</td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="myfile[]" id="myfile[]">'.$row->description .' </td><td><button id="btnViewDoc" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                    onclick="frmViewDOC();">View The Attachment</button></td><td></form></td></tr>';


    }
    $output .='</table>';
    echo $output;
}
```

The ajax return the output but when i click the button in the blade the token is not working and @csrf is displayed instead of being rendered. How do i solve that ?
Please help me out.

Comment: How do you call your fetchFiles function ? Is it the controller ?

Comment: I call using jquery as below, and it is working:

Comment: I call using jquery as below, and it is working:  $.ajax({
                    url:"{{ route('fetchFiles') }}",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{applicant_id:applicant_id, _token:_token,application_id:myRequest_id },
                    success:function(result)
                    {

                        $('#myAttachments').html(result);
                    }

Comment: Alex van Vliet, thank you and please help me I am in need to accomplish this tasks

Comment: Blade is only processed inside a view whose extension is .blade.php. What you could do is either put the template in a file or call the csrf_field() function instead of putting @csrf